# Use markdown email for contact form

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.4

Can we use markdown feature to style out the email template for contact form ? I was using this method to send message from contact form:

Method to send email:

```
        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('example@domain.com');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });
```

`contact.blade.php`

```
    <h3>You have a new email via contact form</h3>
<div>
{{ $bodyMessage }}
</div>
<p>Sent by: {{ $email }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you don't seem to have any issues with your code, I am just going to point you over to the docs, if I have the wrong impression and there is a problem, feel free to comment and I'll update.

As of 5.4, yes. You are best off consulting the documentation over on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#markdown-mailables), it provides in depth instructions on mailables and sending mail in general.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of `mailable` classes in order to use markdown in emails.

Run the command `php artisan make:mail ContactForm` to create a `mailable` class.

In the `ContactForm` class, your `build` method should be something like this:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
        ->markdown('emails.contact');
}
```

You can also associate a markdown view automatically while generating the mailable class by passing the markdown flag to the name of the view as:

```
php artisan make:mail --markdown=view.name
```

In order to send the mail, you can call it like this:

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new ContactForm($data));
```

For accessing the `$data` variable in the `mailable`, you'll have to declare it as a public variable. Any public property defined on your `mailable` class will automatically be made available to the view. Example:

```
class ContactForm extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @param $data
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    ...
}
```

In the view file you can access the variable normally as you'd do in other blade templates. Example:

```
Sender email: {{ $data['email'] }}
```

If you want to build from the blade view instead of markdown replace `markdown` with view in the `ContactForm` class.

You can view more info on the official documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#writing-mailables

Comment: How do I tie my contact form's action with this ContactForm class ?

Comment: If you're referring to accessing the data filled in the website contact form, I've updated the answer for that.